# Is there a way to Upgrade terminal sftp client?

Tags: sftp, binary

The pre-installed sftp binary on macOS sucks. When I use my ubuntu machine, sftp has glorious things like a history and tab completion. I've looked around, and cannot tell a clear cut path to upgrading the binary. Has anyone done this? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install homebrew a macOS package manager.  https://brew.sh/

HomeBrew is most often mentioned these days. sftp appears to be one of the programs you can download.

other package managers are:
MacPort -- BSD licenses
Fink -- GNU General Public License

I'd figure out what sftp client Ubuntu uses and look around for the macOS version.

Comment: Can you specify the exact name of the formula for installing sftp using Homebrew?

Comment: Agreed with Nimesh. I don't see it on homebrew, I checked before asking the question.

Comment: Try `brew install openssh` and edit your $PATH as necessary.

Comment: @justin https://www.openssh.com/ --> https://man.openbsd.org/sftp.1    Thanks for the assist da4

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr: `openssh` homebrew package

---

Right now, if you `which sftp`, you'll see `/usr/bin/sftp`, which is Apple's crippled version of the program. You can install the latest vanilla OpenSSH (includes `ssh`, `sftp`, `scp`, `ssh-agent`, etc) to solve the problem.

Assuming you have Homebrew installed:

`brew install openssh`

Now it's installed. However, if you run `which sftp`, you might still see the old `/usr/bin/sftp` and not the Homebrew one installed at `/usr/local/bin/sftp`. We don't want to overwrite Apple's files (generally not a good idea) so we'll just set the Homebrew binaries as a higher priority in your terminal.

Adjust your PATH in your `.zshrc`:

`export PATH=$(brew --prefix)/bin:$PATH`

Open a new terminal and you'll probably see `which sftp` return `/usr/local/bin/sftp`. Done.